Migrating Xamarin.iOS to NET8.0-ios breaks WCF DataContracts with EnumValue attributed enums
I'm in the process of migrating a Xamarin.iOS app to net8.0-ios. I'm finding that some WCF service methods are broken which seem to be related to the wrong serializer being used from what I can tell. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.9.6 which is the latest as of this writing. It's a basic WCF service call to a service I host which returns a DataContract with an array of a class which contains an Enum. The enum is decorated with DataContract and each Enum value is decorated with EnumValue and there is an assignment for the 0 value. No matter what I try the enum value is always 0 in the returned array containing a list of this enum object. There are no DataSets in the return value as I've read there is an issue in net8-ios with using the Xml serializer instead of the DataContract serializer. Does anyone have any tips to resolve this as it seems WCF is broken in net8.0-ios.

This might help: All Enums evaluates to 0 when sending a request to a WCF service from a WCF test client.
